# Powering my 5 volt project with AA batteries

Tags: power-supply, batteries, voltage-regulator, circuit-design, dc-dc-converter

I am thinking about using 1 AA Battery with [these battery holders](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32825327704.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.4cab3b3cYIBfi3&algo_pvid=17c60709-bb21-40a9-8cc2-f05842a5dfaf&algo_expid=17c60709-bb21-40a9-8cc2-f05842a5dfaf-8&btsid=0ab6fa8115909557316475936e8fe9&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) and [this boost converter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32967901132.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.3e503c007qI8zC&mp=1) to power my 5 Volt arduino project, My project will pull about 100mA. Is there any problem with doing this? I don't see any issue with using these together to power my project, but I wanted to get other's opinions that before I buy these products. Thanks for the help!

Comment: 100mA * 5V = 500mW. Assuming 80 percent efficiency, that means the input power will be around 625mW. So, you should get several hours of use. But these dodgy ali-baba supplies often work far worse than advertised. It is actually pretty tricky to run a boost regulator all the way down to 1V and below while still putting out 5V at 100mA. If, for example, the supply cuts out at 1.2V or 1.1V, then you will have MUCH less battery life. If you could run it from 2AA batteries you would be much more likely to have a good result.

Comment: 2 or even 3 AA batteries would be a much better bet.

Comment: Yes, 2AAA or 3AAA is also a possibility if space is tight.

Comment: Can someone explain why two AA would be better compared to one??

Comment: Also would these batteries be connected in parallel or series?

Comment: multiple cells would increase the total power that is available ... series connected so that the boost regulator would have a higher input voltage to work with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's your run-time requirement?  With 100 mA @ 5 V that's 0.5 W.  Assuming an efficiency of maybe 80%, that means the input current from your 1.5 cell (say at 1.3V average voltage) will be 416mA, rising to 625mA at 1V cell voltage.

Your boost converter operates down to 1V, so looking at the discharge curves for a typical AA alkaline battery gives a run time of maybe 3.5 hours or so.

[image]

Comment: This makes sense...! I didn't realize that the boost converter would amplify the amount of current coming out of the battery cell, I just thought the cell would be draining 100mA even with the boost

Comment: @JordanHarris: DC-DC converters and AC tranformers pass power (voltage times current), so if the output voltage is higher than the input voltage, the input current will be higher than the output current by the same ratio, and some power will be lost in the conversion.